# Create a dict of list using python from csv

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dictionary

I have a csv file with data as below

```
XPATH,ColumName,CSV_File_Name,ParentKey
/integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity/integrationEntityDetails/supplier/forms/form[]/id,id,integrationEntityDetailsForms.csv,
/integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity/integrationEntityHeader/attachments/attachment[]/id,aid,integrationEntityDetailsForms.csv,
/integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity/integrationEntityDetails/supplier/forms/form[]/records/record[]/Internalid,Internalid,integrationEntityDetailsForms.csv,
/integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity/integrationEntityDetails/supplier/forms/form[]/records/record[]/isDelete,FormId,integrationEntityDetailsForms.csv,
/integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity/integrationEntityDetails/supplier/forms/form[]/records/record[]/fields/field[]/id,SupplierFormRecordFieldId,integrationEntityDetailsForms.csv,
/integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity/integrationEntityDetails/supplier/forms/form[]/records/record[]/fields/field[]/value,SupplierFormRecordFieldValue,integrationEntityDetailsForms.csv,
/integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity/integrationEntityHeader/integrationTrackingNumber,integrationTrackingNumber,integrationEntityDetailsForms.csv,Y
/integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity/integrationEntityHeader/referenceCodeForEntity,referenceCodeForEntity,integrationEntityDetailsForms.csv,Y
/integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity/integrationEntityDetails/supplier/requestId,requestId,integrationEntityDetailsForms.csv,Y
/integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity/integrationEntityDetails/supplier/id,supplier_id,integrationEntityDetailsForms.csv,Y
```

[sample csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JANNW.png)

I wanted to create a dictionary of list which would result like this basically split on [] and put all put the [0] on the first list for every element . discard the records which dont have [] . This will give the list of tag at each level.

```
{ 1 : ['integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.supplier.forms.form', 'integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.attachments.attachment'] , 2 : ['integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.supplier.forms.form.records.record'] , 3 : ['integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.supplier.forms.form.records.record.fields.field'] }
```

so far i have reached till splitting the string using [] , converting the / to . and the list are split up and accumulated. But i am stuck in putting back to dictonary of list . Which will give me the level at which the each tag are

`df_process_sub_explode_Level` gives the individual line for each row in that csv, but need to remove duplciates and popualte to the dict .

```
CSV_File_Name = []
with open(process_config_csv, newline='') as csvfile:
        DataCaptured = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in DataCaptured:
                if row['CSV_File_Name'] not in CSV_File_Name:
                        CSV_File_Name.append(row['CSV_File_Name'])

df_process = []
df_process_all_col = []
df_process_explode_Level = dict()
for items in CSV_File_Name:
        df_subset_process = []
        df_subset_list_all_cols = []
        with open(process_config_csv, newline='') as csvfile:
                DataCaptured = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
                for row in DataCaptured:
                    df_process_sub_explode_Level = []
                    if row['CSV_File_Name'] in items:
                            df_subset_process.append(row['XPATH'].replace("/",".").split('[]')[0].replace(".","",1))
                            df_subset_list_all_cols.append(row['XPATH'].replace("/",".").replace("[]","").replace(".","",1))
                            if "[]" in row['XPATH']:
                                print(row['XPATH'])
                                df_process_sub_explode_Level=row['XPATH'].replace("/",".").replace(".","",1).split('[]')
                                del df_process_sub_explode_Level[-1]
                                df_process_sub_explode_Level = list(accumulate(df_process_sub_explode_Level))
                                for explodeitems in range(len(df_process_sub_explode_Level)):
                                    df_process_explode_Level[explodeitems].append(df_process_sub_explode_Level[explodeitems])
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 17, in <module>
KeyError: 0
```

Please guide in putting back to the dict of list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from csv import DictReader
from collections import defaultdict

with open('data.csv') as fp:
    csv_reader = DictReader(fp)
    data = [row['XPATH'].strip('/').replace('/', '.').split('[]') for row in csv_reader]

res = defaultdict(set)
for x in data:
    if len(x) > 1:
        res[len(x) -1].add(''.join(x[: -1]))
res = {k: list(v) for k, v in res.items()}
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: ['integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.attachments.attachment',
  'integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.supplier.forms.form'],
 2: ['integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.supplier.forms.form.records.record'],
 3: ['integration-outbound:IntegrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.supplier.forms.form.records.record.fields.field']}
```